# error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6 : two behaviors for same docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am developing an Erlang-OTP application, for that I use a docker image.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM centos
LABEL Name=myimage Version=2.0.0

RUN set -e \
   && yum -y install \
      autoconf \
      gcc \
      gcc-c++ \
      git \
      glibc-devel \
      make \
      ncurses-devel \
      tar \
      curl


ENV SSL_VERSION="1.0.2p"

RUN set -e \
   && mkdir -p /tmp/openssl \
   && cd /tmp \
   && curl -fSL -o openssl.sha256   http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${SSL_VERSION}.tar.gz.sha256 \
   && curl -fSL -o openssl.tar.gz http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${SSL_VERSION}.tar.gz \
   && SHA=$(printf "%s  openssl.tar.gz" `cat openssl.sha256` | sha256sum -c -); if [ "openssl.tar.gz: OK" != "${SHA}" ]; then exit 3; fi \
   && tar -zxf openssl.tar.gz -C /tmp/openssl --strip-components=1 \
   && cd /tmp/openssl \
   && ./Configure \
         --prefix=/usr/local/ssl \
         --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl \
      linux-x86_64 \
      shared \
   && make -j4 \
   && make install \
   && rm -Rf /tmp/openssl*

ENV OTP_VERSION="20.3.6"
ENV WITH_NATIVE=true

RUN set -e \
   && mkdir -p /tmp/otp_src \
   && cd /tmp \
   && curl --tlsv1.2 -fSL -o otp_src.tar.gz https://github.com/erlang/otp/archive/OTP-20.3.6.tar.gz \
   && tar -zxf otp_src.tar.gz -C /tmp/otp_src --strip-components=1 \
   && cd /tmp/otp_src \
   && ./otp_build autoconf \
   && ./configure \
         --prefix=/usr/local/otp \
         --enable-threads \
         --enable-smp-support \
         --enable-kernel-poll \
         --disable-dynamic-ssl-lib \
         --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl \
         `test "${WITH_NATIVE}" = "true" && echo "--enable-hipe --enable-native-libs"` \
   && make -j4 \
   && make install \
   && ln -s /usr/local/otp_${OTP_VERSION} /usr/local/otp \
   && rm -Rf /tmp/otp_src*

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/otp/bin

RUN set -e \
   && yum -y install \
      which


ENV REBAR3_VERSION="3.6.1"

RUN set -xe \
    && REBAR3_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/archive/${REBAR3_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && REBAR3_DOWNLOAD_SHA256="40b3c85440f3235c7b149578d0211bdf57d1c66390f888bb771704f8abc71033" \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/rebar3-src \
    && curl --tlsv1.2 -fSL -o rebar3-src.tar.gz "$REBAR3_DOWNLOAD_URL" \
    && echo "$REBAR3_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 rebar3-src.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xzf rebar3-src.tar.gz -C /usr/src/rebar3-src --strip-components=1 \
    && rm rebar3-src.tar.gz \
    && cd /usr/src/rebar3-src \
    && HOME=$PWD ./bootstrap \
    && install -v ./rebar3 /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/rebar3-src

RUN mkdir /myimage
WORKDIR /myimage
```

Commands to run `docker-compose`

```
sudo docker-compose build
sudo docker-compose run --rm myimage bash
```

When I try to run production tar created by `Ubuntu-18.04`, I get:

> error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I dont get any error while compiling. When I create this tar from `Debian-9`, it runs without error.

Debian machine has locally installed `erlang-otp`, but Ubuntu doesnt have.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Docker's known issue #37531](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37531)

To fix dependencies, you might try:

1. Either upgrade `Docker` to 17.02

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sudo bash
```

2. or install lib inside of container.
   Since your container based on Centos (`FROM centos`), so try `yum install`

```
rpm -ql libXtst-devel-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: I have `Docker version 19.03.7`